# Public API is giving me CORS error when calling axios in create-react-app but all is well in Chrome and Postman

Tags: reactjs, cors, axios, fetch

Forgive me for the obvious error I am obviously committing...

I understand CORS, how and why it's used.  But I'm missing the blindingly obvious in this instance.

I'm trying to access a publicly available API that should work fine (I've been assured)

If I hit the endpoint in Chrome, or in Postman, all works fine: wonderful JSON is returned.

When I try to do the same using `axios` from within my create-react-app's `componentDidMount`, I get a CORS error, specifically

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://some-interesting-url/sub-url?blabla=blip&foo=bar' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

What is it I'm failing to grasp?  Is there anything I can do from my end? (I have no control over the server)

Comment: Try to use `proxy` key and value as URL in package.json. https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development

Comment: @VinayakBagaria -- thanks.  I tried that, using their server as the URL value, but it did nothing.

Answer (score 2):

The Postman app is not a browser so it isn't bound by the rules of CORS. In a browser too, trying to access a URL directly doesn't trigger Cross-Origin-Request-Sharing policies. CORS, by definition will only affects the 'cross-origin' requests made from background JS code of a web-page, to another web-page or API not hosted on same domain name.

Based on the error posted, the API in question is not sending `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. If it's possible to get the API changed, that you should get the header added to response (with value '*', or your domain name). However if that's not possible, then you'd need to route the request through a web-server that you own and include this header there. This kind of does work like a proxy, albeit for a specialized use-case.

If you already have some server side application running, you can simply add another end point to your application. A call to this new end point should trigger the 'Public API' call, and send the response back to client. Since the server side program (eg PHP/Python/NodeJS) would never be a browser, they will not face the CORS issues. If your original web-page is also loaded from same web-server, then the response header can be skipped.

Comment: Thanks very much -- it's weird, since this API is part of a coding test for a front-end React position where I'm simply processing API requests.  If it were a full-stack role I'd say, well, it's a tricky situation to solve, but it's hard to believe this is part of the brief....